# PyQt5: How to click a button to start the paint?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qpushbutton

The following code makes a button and a rectangle. I would like to change it, so that the rectangle is drawn when the button is clicked.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.btn = QPushButton("Paint", self)
        self.btn.move(100, 100)
        # self.btn.clicked.connect(self.paintEvent())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I have tried several times but none of them worked." Show or don't bother mentioning it. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `paintEvent()` method is called internally by Qt, it should not be called directly but through the `update()` method, but in your case you want to do it when a certain condition is used, before that you must create a flag that indicates that it should be drawn, all of the above is implemented in the following code:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.flag = False

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.btn = QPushButton("Paint", self)
        self.btn.move(100, 100)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.show()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.update()


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
            qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)
```